# Is there a paper that is not absorptive, but works like a toilet paper?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am wondering how to prevent the absorption upward from the water. Can this happen with materials other than a paper? Also, looking for a less absorptive type of toilet paper. Thank you.

Comment: saturate it with oil? Transparent  wrap on the water side, or aluminum foil?

Answer (score 1):

you can stop the absorption by applying to it a very thin coating of something with extremely low surface energy, like a silicone oil or teflon. the paper will then "reject" the water and refuse to absorb it.

Comment: I was thinking of lycopodium powder myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can happen with other materials. The rise of he moisture in your paper towel is due to the capillary effect, and there's no way to prevent it that I know of. Try using some other material with a less porous structure; if its purpose is to act as a towel you're unlikely to eliminate the effect completely, but there probably are materials where it is less.